# How to find a string pattern in preg_match_all match array?

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

I have a string with html code. It has lot of urls formats. I used preg_match_all to get all the urls. Now i want to loop through $match2 array and only print the urls that has ".m3u8" some where in the full url. var_dump($match2) prints all the urls correctly but my for loop keep giving me this error;

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Array to string conversion
```

could any one help me fix this problem ?Thanks in advance.

php code:

```
$regex2 = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";

preg_match_all($regex2,$code,$match2);
var_dump($match2);

for($i = 0; $i < count($match2); $i++){

  if (strpos($match2[$i],'.m3u8') !== false) {
    echo "<br>".$match2[$i];
    } else {
       //do nothing
    }
 }
```

Comment: `var_dump($match2);` You already do the right thing. Look at the output of it and think again through which array you want to loop through.

Comment: Thanks i changed $match2 to $match2[0] and it wroked!

Comment: Now you are even able to self-answer your question, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed $match2 to $match2[0] and it wroked!